# Anchoring rotated text to parent element's ceiling

Tags: html, css, text, transform

I have some text that I've rotated -90deg. Does anyone know a way to get it to anchor to the ceiling of the parent element?

So far I've been able to anchor only to the floor:

http://jsfiddle.net/tpm3f

**HTML:**

```
<div>
    <h2>hello, world</h2>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
div { height: 300px; background: red; position: relative; }
h2 {
    color: white;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 2.5em;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: bottom left;
    position: absolute;
    left: 1.5em;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Changing `bottom: 0` to `top: 0` produces a weird result; the text is neither anchored to the ceiling by its left nor its right side.

Does anyone know a pure CSS way round this?

Comment: Like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/tpm3f/8/)?

Comment: Sorry, that's still bottom-anchored from what I can see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you need the element locked to the top and the left corner have a look at something like

```
h2 {
    color: white;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 2.5em;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: top right;
    position: absolute;
    right: 100%;
    top: 0;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8gsuD/1/

Comment: Ah, nice! Didn't think of using `right: 100%` to shift it over :)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
h2 {
     -webkit-transform-origin: top right;
      top: 0;
    }
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8gsuD/)

Comment: Not quite - that centres the text horizontally in the middle of the parent, but it DOES anchor to the top, so +1 for that.